How can I pass a file to a function and store the files' contents in an array?
How can I pass a file to a function and store the files' contents in an array?
I have an assignment for a beginner C++ class. The assignment (or at least the part I need help with) is to pass in 2 files from command line arguments, one file contains every year since 1920, the other contains the name of the baseball team that won the World Series that year. I then need to pass one of these in to a function to store it in an array.
I have to use namespace std but I cannot use vector as we have not learned it yet. This is a beginner class and vector comes in the next class.
Any help pointing me in the right direction, or an example if you've done it in another program, would be so greatly appreciated. My files have to be passed into main() through arguments (which I have successfully done and tested) and then somehow pass one of those files to the ReadFile() function. fs is the teams file and fileName is the file with the dates/years.
This is the ReadFile() function and the required parameters. This is where I am struggling. Nothing in this portion of the code can be changed as the professor wrote this code and wants us to build upon it, but I need help with passing the file to this function so I can store the data in an array.
// This function takes a file name and reads in data, storing it in a string array     that is used 
// by the rest of the program. Use this function to read the team names or the   corresponding dates. 
// The function should return true on success or false on failure.
bool ReadFile(string fileName, string data[], const int maxArraySize)
{

}

This is what I have in main() so far:
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        cout << "Error! Not enough file names. Expecting 2!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Const representing the number of lines of data in both files.
    const int SIZE_DATA = 120; 
    char choice;

    // Work here
    ifstream fs;
    ifstream fileName;
    
    fs.open(argv[1]);
    if (!fs)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file " << argv[1] << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << argv[1] << " opened successfully" << endl;
    }

    fileName.open(argv[2]);
    if (!fileName)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file " << argv[2] << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << argv[2] << " opened successfully" << endl;
    } 
}


I emailed my professor for help and this is the response I got:

You need to get the file names from the arguments passed into main. Don't not hard code the file names anywhere in your program.


Something like... auto Read(istream& in) -> vector<string> { vector<string> result; string line; while (getline(in, line)) { result.push_back(move(line)); } return result; }  ...?

I can't use a vector.

Oh, that's unfortunate.  A std::vector is the beginners container type.  A C++ array or a C-style array are much more advanced.

If you can't use std::vector someone is not teaching you C++. Unless this would be an excercise to make you write your own vector (e.g. in a datastructures class)

The function you have been give takes three parameters, the file name, the array to fill, and the size of that array. So you would call it something like this.
string filename = argv[1];
string data[SIZE_DATA];
ReadFile(filename, data, SIZE_DATA);

Note that it is a mistake to open the file in main. Clearly because the file name is being passed to the ReadFile function you are expected to open the file in the ReadFile function, not in main.
There is a problem with the ReadFile function however. There is no way for this function to indicate how many items have been read. So the function can fill up the data array but cannot communicate how many items have been placed into the array. This seems like a serious flaw to me, I would ask your professor about that.
There's no way for me to know how to write the function because in part it depends on the file format (which you didn't specify). Something like this would seem to be reasonable though, adapt to whatever your precise needs are
bool ReadFile(string fileName, string data[], const int maxArraySize)
{
    ifstream file(fileName); // open the file
    if (!file.is_open())     // check if the file is open
        return false;        // return false on failure
    int i = 0;               // initially zero items in array
    while (i < maxArraySize && file >> data[i]) // read until either the array is full or a read fails
        ++i;                 // one more item added to array
    return true;             // return true on success
}

